# Can the "Accept" HTTP header have a "charset" parameter?

Tags: http

I have encountered an HTTP client that uses the following header:

```
Accept: application/vnd.api+json; charset=utf-8'
```

According to the [HTTP spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-5.3.2), `Accept` headers *can* have parameters. The most common one being the `q` parameter, which sets the priority of different content types. However, there are a number of reasons I don't think `charset` is a valid `Accept` parameter:

- `Accept` already has the `Accept-Charset` parameter, which seems like it makes this redundant
- [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept) doesn't include it in their documentation on `Accept`, even though they do include in on their `Content-Type` page
- Werkzeug, the flask HTTP parser, doesn't bother to parse charsets for `Accept`, even though it does for `Content-Type`

So, it seems this `Accept; charset` is *unusual*. But is it wrong?

Comment: I believe the title update is more reflective of the goal.. if not, revert.

Comment: I'm not really asking about servers, I'm asking about correctness in terms of the spec

Comment: Doesn't the standard explicitly mention `charset` as an example of an acceptable parameter? "Each media-range might be followed by zero or more applicable media type parameters (e.g., `charset`)".

Comment: Ah, yep I missed that. That answers my question.

Answer (score 0):

You quoted the spec, which says they are ok. What else needs to be said?

Comment: The spec says that *parameters in general* are okay, but it doesn't say that `charset` is okay.

Comment: It doesn't need to say that.